# HashMap not saving entries

Tags: java, hashmap, textures

My problem is that, I'm trying to make a resource loader that saves past textures to a HashMap with their locations as their key. It works perfectly when it is loading images outside of the package but when it is trying to load an internal image it just wont save.

This is my code for my resource loader

```
public Map<String,BufferedImage> loads = new HashMap<String,BufferedImage>();

public BufferedImage loadImage(String imagePath){

    BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(9, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    String location = imagePath.replaceAll("[.]", "/");
    location += ".png";

    //internal
    if(location.startsWith("CLASS_")){
        if(loads.get(location) != null){
            System.out.println("OLD");
            return loads.get(location);
        }else{
            location = location.replaceAll("CLASS_", "");
            try{
                temp = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("net/minegeek360/platformer/assets/"+location));
                loads.put(location, temp);
            }catch(Exception e){System.err.println("CANT LOAD IMAGE");}
            System.out.println("NEW | "+temp);
        }
    //external
    }else{
        try{
            if(loads.get(location) != null){
                //System.out.println("LOADED ORIGIONAL IMAGE");
                return loads.get(location);
            }else{
                temp = ImageIO.read(new File("assets/textures/"+location));
                //System.out.println("LOADED NEW IMAGE");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        loads.put(location, temp);
    }

    return temp;
}
```

As I said the external loading works perfectly, its just the internal loading that the problem. It loads all of the images correctly so I know the BufferedImages are not the issue, that's why I think its the HashMaps.

Comment: You get an exception?

Comment: What does the debugger show at the point where you put() the internal one into the map ?

Comment: The loads never gets anything added to it! Even though its in my code, it does nothing!

Comment: Have you tried printing out all of the <String, BufferedImage> pairs from your map?

Comment: When I use System.out.println("SAVED IMAGE      | "+loads.get(location)); at the end of the code it returns the image. When I use it at the beginning of the code it returns null!!

Answer (score 2):

When the data is put into the map, the prefix "CLASS_" is removed from location which is being used as the key.

However, when the data is being queried from the map, the prefix is still present.

Could you please try out this code for the internal part and provide the output from the console?

```
if(location.startsWith("CLASS_")){
    location = location.replaceFirst("CLASS_", "");
    if(loads.get(location) != null){
        System.out.println("OLD");
        return loads.get(location);
    } else {
        try{
            temp = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("net/minegeek360/platformer/assets/"+location));
            System.out.println("Loading image, current size: " + loads.size());
            loads.put(location, temp);
            System.out.println("Image loaded,  new size:     " + loads.size());
        }catch(Exception e){System.err.println("CANT LOAD IMAGE");}
        System.out.println("NEW | "+temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not that. I've tested it many different ways and it doesn't add it to the map.

Answer (score 0):

> The loads never gets anything added to it! Even though its in my code, it does nothing!

Doubtful.

You check for internally-loaded images like so:

```
if(location.startsWith("CLASS_")){
    if(loads.get(location) != null){
```

If you don't find one then you load it like this:

```
        location = location.replaceAll("CLASS_", "");
        try{
            temp = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("net/minegeek360/platformer/assets/"+location));
            loads.put(location, temp);
```

You certainly store the images, but the test for a previously-loaded internal image will never succeed because you store them using a different key (with all appearances of `"CLASS_"` removed) than you later try to use to look them up.

Comment: I have now changed the code. When it is loading the location it does System.out.println("loading location | "+location); and when it saves it does System.out.println("NEW              | "+location); The results were:      NEW              | CLASS_textures/tiles/blocks/grass.png
loading location | CLASS_textures/tiles/blocks/grass.png
NEW              | CLASS_textures/tiles/blocks/grass.png
loading location | CLASS_textures/tiles/blocks/grass.png

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had multiple instances of the same loader. So I just made my files access only one instance.